# GitLab: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, repository, gitlab

I created my project and added my ssh-key (both over webinterface), but when I try to push something to the repo, I get this error: "Could not read from the repository". This might be due to the fact, that the .git-project-file does not exist in the /home/git/repositories/[group]/ folder.

The gitlab-check returns:

```
[Group] / [Project] ... can't create, repository is empty
```

### Error when pushing to repository

**git remote add origin git@myserver.com:[group]/[project].git**

**git push -u origin master**

```
fatal: '/home/git/repositories/[group]/[project].git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

### What might have caused the error

**ls -ld /home/git/repositories/[group]/[project].git**

```
File not found.
```

*Why was the file not created?*

### Infos about my setup

**ls -ld /home/ /home/git/**

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 28 15:04 /home/
drwxr-xr-x 8 git  git  4096 Aug 31 11:33 /home/git/
```

**ll /home/git**

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 git  git  4096 Aug 31 11:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 28 15:04 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git   220 Aug 28 15:04 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git  3637 Aug 28 15:04 .bashrc
drwx------  2 git  git  4096 Aug 29 19:52 .cache/
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git    88 Aug 31 11:33 .gitconfig
drwxr-xr-x 16 git  git  4096 Aug 29 15:32 gitlab/
drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git  4096 Aug 28 15:09 gitlab-satellites/
drwxr-xr-x  8 git  git  4096 Aug 29 19:51 gitlab-shell/
-rw-------  1 git  git    13 Aug 29 15:36 .mysql_history
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git   675 Aug 28 15:04 .profile
drwxrws---  5 git  git  4096 Aug 29 16:15 repositories/
drwx------  2 git  git  4096 Aug 31 11:47 .ssh/
-rw-------  1 git  git  3453 Aug 29 16:03 .viminfo
```

**sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info**

```
RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     Ubuntu 13.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p247
Gem Version:    2.0.3
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:    6.0.0
Revision:   6c1c284
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://myserver.com
HTTP Clone URL: http://myserver.com/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@myserver.com:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.7.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

**sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check**

```
RAILS_ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.0 ? ... OK (1.7.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... 
[Group] / [Project] ... repository is empty

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
Projects have satellites? ... 
[Group] / [Project] ... can't create, repository is empty
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.1)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

**ssh -T git@myserver.com**

```
Welcome to GitLab, Christian Hammer!
```

**cat /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys**

```
command="/home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-2",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa [key] [email]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[(Re)starting sidekiq](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3520#issuecomment-20223956) solved the problem:

```
sudo -Hu git RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sidekiq:start
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given, it is not able to create.  Please check what exists inside of repositories/[group] directory.
If your repository is a bare repository (one which does not have working directory), then it is a convention to use a name like [project.git].

Comment: Nothing is inside the directory /repositories/[group]. I used "git remote add origin git@myserver.com:mygroup/myproject.git"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But for me restarting sidekiq did not solve it. So i leave a small solution for the same error message. I  manage the server gitlab is running on, so i created one key for remote ssh access (`gitlab-server.pub`) and another one (`gitlab-repo.pub`) for the repository. In the  gitlab interface i uploaded  `gitlab-repo.pub` but i forgot git to tell which one to use so after updating `~/.ssh/config` [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use#232406) everything works